# Почему не работает метод message.send?

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api, requests

Код имеющийся сейчас:

```
import vk_api
import requests
from vk_api.longpoll import VkLongPoll,VkEventType

vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(token='мой токен')
session_api=vk_session.get_api()
longpool=VkLongPoll(vk_session)

def send_some_msg(id,some_text):
    vk_session.method('message.send',{'user_id':id,'message':some_text})

for event in longpool.listen():
    if event.type==VkEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:
        if event.to_me:

            msg=event.text.lower()
            id=event.user_id

            if msg=='понедельник':
                print(msg, id)
                send_some_msg(id,'Я уже близко')
```

Comment: Его запрещено использовать непроверенным приложениям, читайте документацию

Comment: что значит непроверенное приложение?

Comment: Потому что способ, каким Вы вызвали данный метод, используется с помощью `session_api`, а не `vk_session` в Вашем случае

Comment: я не знаю что там с методом и тем,кто его использует,я дописал 1 букву и все заработало